# Expectation for the sum of E[X^2]

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Is this correct?

[expected value for E[X^2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI8sM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! You're more likely to get good responses if you [follow these guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Generally, it's best to write out the math you're asking about instead of posting a picture, since pictures aren't searchable. You can do this with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the proof in the image is correct. Given $E[X_i^2] = \sigma^2+\mu^2$, we have:

$$ E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n {X_i^2}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n {E[X_i^2]} $$

This first step follows from the [linearity of the expectation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties).

Then, we can substitute in $E[X_i^2] = \sigma^2+\mu^2$:

$$ E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n {X_i^2}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n {(\sigma^2+\mu^2)} $$

Since $\sigma^2+\mu^2$ is a constant, we can factor it out of the summation:

$$ E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n {X_i^2}\right] = (\sigma^2+\mu^2) \sum_{i=1}^n {1} $$

Then, the sum of $1$ iterated $n$ times is simply $n$:

$$ E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n {X_i^2}\right] = n(\sigma^2+\mu^2) .$$